# Android/PC GIS library wanted

Tags: java, android, gis

I have a task to develop an application with some GIS-functions: rendering of the previously downloaded map (with different layers and in different modes), programmatic assignment of markers and tracks, a path searching. It must be implemented under Android and PC (Win) and must be able to work offline. So I need a library which provides capabilities specified above and satisfies some additional conditions.

1. If possible, cross-platform (i.e. with a common core and with a different GUI under PC/Android).
2. Free for commercial use or without requirement of any user license in addition to the developer license.
3. Open-source is preferable (GPL/LGPL/MIT-like is ideal).
4. Java API is preferable.

After some days of googling I came to the conclusion that such a thing didn’t exist at all. There are many open-source GIS products in Java but no one of them is Android-compatible. So my goal is to find a library with an ability to render some map region into the picture and an ability to tell me coordinates by the specified picture pixel. At least I can use different PC-only and Android-only products to develop two different applications parallely.

Please, can anybody suggest me anything applicable for my task. Maybe somebody has some experience in this area. Any information is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is rather vague, I'm not too sure what you are looking for. You might want to check out [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) for a browser-based application, and [Tiles à la Google Maps](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) for rendering your own tiles. Both provide free tools that may be useful to you.

Comment: @Leeward
Now I'm looking for Java/C++/C GIS library for Android. With the abilities specified above (offline map rendering, markers and tracks, path searching). Unfortunately browser-based solution (and therefore JavaScript) isn't suitable for me.

Comment: Try [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) or [GeoAPI](http://www.geoapi.org/), but you will probably still need to render your own tiles with something similar to the resource linked above (which also provides a how-to for implementing it yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not a full GIS library I have used JTS to write code on both PC and android.
The Website is http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm

Whilst the documentation is a little on the light side I have found that it isn't to hard to implement. Using standard drawing functions I have been able to set up some basic GIS applications and mapping functions.